# Propel: Get Raw SQL from Query object?

Tags: php, sql, orm, propel

How do I get the raw SQL statement from a query object in Propel? I need this for debugging purposes.

For example: I would like to have a function as in

```
$rawSql = new BookQuery::create()->filterById(25)->getRawSql();
```

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes; you're after the `toString` method from the [Criteria](http://api.propelorm.org/1.6.9/db_runtime_lib_query_Criteria.html) parent class:

```
$rawSql = (new BookQuery)::create()->filterById(25)->toString();
```

As @jakerella says, the specific values you use for filtering will be bound by the database engine, rather than Propel, and so you'll see the structure of the query but not exactly what will be executed. If you want to see that, then you can check your database query logs, if they're enabled.

Comment: Note that you won't get specific `select` columns in the query above - Propel does that right before the find. Thus you must see something like: `SELECT  FROM book WHERE id=:p1; ... :p1=>25`

Comment: @jakerella: can you expand on that in an answer? I am not sure that makes it clear how to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: @halfer your answer is correct, it's just that Propel binds the `select` columns at the last moment, so you may not see the selected columns in the SQL (notice in my example how there is nothing between `SELECT` and `FROM`). Propel doesn't use `*` to select all columns, it manually adds all necessary columns in each query.

Answer (score 12):

Fulfilling accepted answer, you can use next code **afterwards** query execution.

```
\Propel::getConnection()->getLastExecutedQuery() // Returns fully qualified SQL
```

It allows you to see the **full query** (*including select columns and fetched parameters*) which was sent to database.

---

**UPD**: (*as mentioned by **@bbird***)

This command won't output anything unless `useDebug` is `true`:

```
\Propel::getConnection()->useDebug(true);
```

---

**UPD2**: (*if you are using **Symfony framework***)

One more thing worth mentioning is *PropelORM*+*Symfony*.

If you need to trace SQL it is possible using logs. Propel has it's own [*monolog*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html) channel called `propel` and fully qualified queries are logged with `DEBUG` log level on relevant channel (*`propel.DEBUG`*).

Log/query record looks like this:

```
[2016-10-04 17:00:46] propel.DEBUG: time:  0.000 sec | mem:   24.8 MB | connection: default | SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `last_login` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 123 [] []
```

Comment: Very promising suggestion! I'm looking forward to trying this out.

Comment: Note this command won't output anything unless useDebug is true: $con = Propel::getConnection(); $con->useDebug(true); $con->getLastExecutedQuery();